# Redux doesn't save state even reaching type [Solved]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Update:I think I found my problem I somehow access my state by useSelector(state => state.auth) which didn't save my ordersReducer.

please help me. I have this code that I already reached `SAVE_ORDERS_SUCCESS` but it doesn't save the state of it. Here are my codes. FYI, I have another reducer to update auth and it works.

my call

```
dispatch(getOrdersList())
    .then(() => console.log('save'))
    .catch(err => console.log('eeeS'));
```

api call

```
const getOrdersList = (data = {}) => {
  const url = `get_all_order`;
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  const headers = {
    access_token: user.data.token
  };

  const body = {
    ...data,
    type: data.admin_id ? null : 'super'
  };

  return apiCall(url, body, headers).then(response => response);
};

export default {
  getOrdersList
};
```

My reducer

```
import {
  SAVE_ORDERS_SUCCESS,
  SAVE_ORDERS_FAILURE,
  GETTING_DATA
} from 'actions/types';

const initialState = {
  ordersData: null,
  isLoading: false,
  error: null
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  console.log(' ~ file: getOrdersReducer.js:15 ~ payload:', payload);

  switch (type) {
    case GETTING_DATA:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true, error: null };
    case SAVE_ORDERS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, ordersData: payload.response };
    case SAVE_ORDERS_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

combine

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import auth from './auth';
import message from './message';
import getOrdersReducer from './getOrdersReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  getOrdersReducer,
  auth,
  message
});
```

type and store

```
export const GETTING_DATA = 'GETTING_DATA';
export const SET_MESSAGE = 'SET_MESSAGE';
export const CLEAR_MESSAGE = 'CLEAR_MESSAGE';

export const SAVE_ORDERS_SUCCESS = 'SAVE_ORDERS_SUCCESS';
export const SAVE_ORDERS_FAILURE = 'SAVE_ORDERS_FAILURE';
```

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

I tried to console.log `payload` at case `SAVE_ORDERS_SUCCESS` still see it but the return doesn't save in store.

Comment: It's a little hard to follow without context; where is `SAVE_ORDERS_SUCCESS` dispatched?

Comment: Possibly it should be `ordersData: payload` instead of `ordersData: payload.response`?  But there's not enough information here to do anything more than guess.

Comment: I used  `dispatch(getOrdersList())` to call action type `SAVE_ORDERS_SUCCESS`. I think I found my problem I somehow access my state by `useSelector(state => state.auth)` which didn't save my `ordersReducer`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning a **action** with the `getOrdersList` function simply the response.

The `dispatch` expects this a object with a type and a payload

```js
const { type, payload } = action;
```

But instead receives only the `response`

```js
const getOrdersList = (data = {}) => {
  // ...

  return apiCall(url, body, headers).then((response) => response);
};
```

Since the reducer receives no `type` it will fallback to the `default` and return the `state`. You can solve this by doing this instead:

```js
const getOrdersList = (data = {}) => {
  // ...

  const data = apiCall(url, body, headers).then((response) => response);

  return {
    type: SAVE_ORDERS_SUCCESS,
    payload: data,
  };
};
```

Comment: I found my problems but still thank you!